# How to add results of previous columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure if it is even possible in SQL, will appreciate your response.

I create 4 Case statements to define quantity of sold items (of a specific type).
After that, I want to create another 5th column where I can take an overall sold amount and subtract all those 4 specific types.
I am trying to understand how it can be done in one SQL query. The SUM and division should be done on a row level.

In other words, trying to understand how I can SUM 4 case statements and divide that sum from another column and it all should be in one column.

I hope my explanation makes sense.
p/s I use SQL specifically SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You've only provided a query fragment so the answer is only a query fragment.

You cannot reference column aliases created in the same *level*, you can however create your query as a *derived table* or a *CTE*, and then the columns are available to the outer query, thus

```
with t as (
    select
        p.PDQSLD,
        p.[PDITM#] as [Item Number],
        Sum(PDQSLD) as [Quantity Sold], 
        p.PDWEDT as [Week Ending Date],
        l.SGDWHS as [Default Ship Warehouse], 
        p.PDCHN as [Chain Code],
        case when p.PDCHN = 'DH' then p.PDQSLD else 0 end as DHSLD,
        case when p.PDCHN = 'WM' then p.PDQSLD else 0 end as WMSLD,
        case when p.PDCHN = 'MJ' then p.PDQSLD else 0 end as MJSLD,
        case when p.PDCHN = 'BJ' then p.PDQSLD else 0 end as BJSLD
    from ...
)
select t.*,
PDQSLD - ( DHSLD + WMSLD +  MJSLD + BJSLD ) as OTHRSLD
from t
```

Note that in T-SQL, 'quoted' values are for string literals, if you need to delimit column aliases, use [square brackets].

Comment: thank you for your reply. I still have some issue with selecting from CTE. I have provided the query in my message. Could you let me know where I make a mistake? I do get an error right now "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."

Comment: @Davidskis your case expression is nonsensical, `case when..` *then* what? Do you even need a case expression? I have no idea what your intentions are.

Comment: I have posted everything in my original query. I don't need anything else.  You said I had provided only a part of the query so I posted everything.

Comment: @Davidskis your original query had a partially formed case expression which on its own is incomplete. Do you just want the new derived column to be the sum of these? Your question is tantalisingly incomplete. `case when <expression> end` is a syntax error.

Comment: I think you are right. My apology. I just need a calculation p.[PDQSLD] - ( DHSLD + WMSLD +  MJSLD + BJSLD ) I don't really need CASE for this. Can you let me know how I need to select them (from that temp table or CTE)

Comment: Just remove the case expression fragment as I've done in the answer above.

Comment: it doesn't work. "PDQSLD - (DHSLD + WMSLD +  MJSLD + BJSLD) 
from" is underlined as a mistake and it gives an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."